# Accessing pixel pointer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

Can you explain to me how the accessing pixel has been done in the double loop ? how do they change rows and cols and pixel's value?

```
for(int i=0;i<cv_ptr->image.rows;i++)
    {   
        float* ptr_img_A = cv_ptr->image.ptr<float>(i); 
        
        for(int j=0;j<cv_ptr->image.cols;j++)
        {                   
            *ptr_img_B=255*(*ptr_img_A)/3.5;
             ptr_img_A++;   
        }           
    }
```

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182834/accessing-pixel-pointer/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-03**:
ptr_img_B seems to be missing here.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-04**:
how so ?..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-04**:
It is neither declared nor advanced ever.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-04**:
Ya I just pick up this part of code just to understand the accessing pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is fairly normal pointer arithmetic, usually explained in a second or third computer science/C++ course.

This page explains it fairly well: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

The [OpenCV Mat Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) describes how to access data in OpenCV images.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-04**:
I don't want courses in pointer, my question was how we can use pointer to access to pixel.
Anyway thank you

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-04**:
The sample you posed uses pointer arithmetic to access the value of each pixel in row-major order.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-04**:
and what about the cols ? because as I know the image is like a two dimension table we can access to each pixel via i,j.. but using pointer I can't see clearly how we do that !

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-07-04**:
Same as in the question you asked here http://answers.ros.org/question/173933/accessing-pixel-image-c/ ptr_img_A = cv_ptr->image.ptr(i); Gives you a pointer to the first element in the i'th row. ptr_img_A++ changes ptr_img_A from pointing to one column to pointing the next column...